# Using wildcard in Preg Match

Tags: php, regex

I am making a PHP scraper and have the following piece of code that grabs the title from the page by looking inside the span `uiButtonText`. However I want to now scan for a hyperlink and have it pregmatch `<a href="*" class="thelink" onclick="*">(.*)</a>`.

The stars I want to be wild cards so that I can get the hyperlink from the page even if the href and onclick changes for each one.

`if (preg_match("/<span class=\"uiButtonText\">(.*)<\/span>/i", $cache, $matches)){print($matches[1] . "\n");}else {}`

My Full Code:

```
<?php
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/MauiNuiBotanicalGardens/info";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$cache = $html;

if (preg_match("/<span class=\"uiButtonText\">(.*)<\/span>/i", $cache, $matches))    {print($matches[1] . "\n");}else {}
?>`
```

Comment: use DOM, not regular expressions

Comment: Type google.com in address bar, search for `DOM Document in PHP`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, im still learning PHP would it be possible to expand a bit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Comment: don't lie and say you are google bot when your not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to stick with your regex, try this:

```
$html = '<span class="uiButtonText"><a href="http://google.com" class="thelink" onclick="#">Google!</a></span>';

preg_match("/<span class=\"uiButtonText\"><a href=\".*\" class=\"thelink\" onclick=\".*\">(.*)<\/a><\/span>/i", $html, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

> Output:
>  Google!

A better way would be to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and doing something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.facebook.com/MauiNuiBotanicalGardens/info");
foreach($html->find("a.thelink") as $link){
    echo $link->innertext . "<BR>";
}
```

Above is not tested, but should work